# Can I connect to network A from network B when they are at two separate physical locations?

Tags: linux, remote-connection

I'm attempting to connect to my wifi network at home to be able to access the external hard drive that I have connected to my router from my girlfriends house. My wifi is at location A and her wifi is at location B. I want to connect to location A from location B.

Even if this is something that needs to be wrote... i'm dedicated enough lol

I've attempted to google this but I guess I'm not asking google the right question

Answer (score 0):

You can use sftp or ftp to do that. Just make sure the location where hard drive is located has a static public ip.

I would recommend using sftp since its more secure and easy to setup.You would need to connect the hard drive to computer running linux and enable ssh (automatic enabled on most distro) then you need to login to your router (location b) and port forward the port 22 to the ip of the linux computer (make the ip static) and that should be it.

Go to your computer on location b and download winscp. Put in the public ip pf loaction b and you can navigate to your harddrive.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that the whole point of computer networking? To be able to connect from anywhere to anywhere?

However, you haven't mentioned whether both of you are on the same or on different ISPs. That makes some difference in relation to ip address resolution. For example, suppose your ISP router has an address of 172.x.y.1, and you have 172.x.y.5 and your girlfriend has 172.x.y.9, then it is possible you can make a LAN connection and transfer files.

However, if both of you are on different ISPs, then public address comes into play. You can use SSH or VPN to connect to her computer. Or, you can take advantage of the bittorrent protocol. Have her make torrent files of the contents of the harddrive, and upload them privately on some torrent website. You can then do the rest.

Cheers, I am a beginner myself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this - as you are likely each behind a separate NAT connection  (because thats how most ISP's work) you will need to somehow link these connections together.  There are multiple ways to do this.

I would break the problem down into a few parts, the key decisions being -

1. How do you want to access the fileserver.  If you want it to "just appear"
   more-or-less as if you were on the same LAN you will need to look at a
   VPN or similar to bridge the networks together.  If you just want to 
   be able to access it using a web browser or FTP or SSH you may be able
   to get away with something simpler, like port forwarding.
2. How are you going to find the remote servers IP address ? The easiest way
   may be to configure Dynamic DNS, or maybe one or both of you have a static
   IP address?
3. Are you going to try connect only to the fileserver, or do you want to
   connect to everything on each others network.

Its a bit hard to provide a more exact answer without having narrowed down the playing field - you should look at OpenVPN for creating a VPN network between the sites as well as Port mapping and Dynamic DNS - How you do port mapping will depend on your router.